# How to have cache to express-graphql?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

In my nodejs application I use graphql with [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql).

I can't see any cache option that library provide. How should I do the cache for graphql requests? (I need to support `get` and `post`)

Comment: The provided library is depracated. If you have to use it you may want to implement the GraphQL caching with Redis: https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-apply-redis-cache-to-graphql-in-node-application-407c57fc9ab8 If you are not afraid of using the outdated/not-supported packages you can also try this one: https://github.com/ilkerkaran/express-graphql-redis but the best recommendation would be to use the most up-to-date solution.